# Why does Visual Studio Code recognize numpy but not matplotlib.pyplot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I can use numpy library but not the matplotlib.pyplot library even though I have installed both

The example code in visual studio code:

```
mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([0, 6])
ypoints = np.array([0, 250])
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)

plt.show()
```

I get in the terminal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

However, when I type pip3 show matplotlib, I get the message that it is alr installed:

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.7.1
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: /home/huinker/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

However, VS code works with other library like numpy. Example code

```
import numpy
A, B=numpy.array(list(map(int, input().split()))), numpy.array(list(map(int, input().split())))
print (numpy.inner(A, B))
print (numpy.outer(A, B))
```

the code works with numpy library. when i try in the termial pip3 show numpy:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.24.3
Summary: Fundamental package for array computing in Python
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email:License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/huinker/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: contourpy, matplotlib
```

What is my problem with the environment?

Comment: most likely Visual Studio Code is not using the interpreter you think it is using, check with `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Quick guess: did you name your own file `matplotlib.py` or have such file in the directory? Current directory gets prepended to path, so current files get searched before the installed ones

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki wouldn't he get another error?

Comment: try using conda or mamba for a faster version of it, pip was a pain and in conda never had issues with that stuff, you can even use pip in conda and it works just as you expect

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki please tag a person when replying to another commenter so they can see it. In this case David (I can't tag multiple people in one comment). I agree with use of neutral language until known, SO also has a rules to be mindful of it.

Comment: @stunlocked that advice is unrelated to the question asked and can cause even more interpreter confusion (in case if it's what dankel444 said and not what I said)

Comment: @h4z3 i changed the name and it works now. it is the file name problem

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the VS Code [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) regarding environments. I am pretty sure the guess of @dankal444 is correct. Type `Ctrls+Shift+P` to open the command palette and search for `Python: Select Interpreter`. Choose the one called `/home/huinker/.local/lib/python3.10/`.

[image: how to select python interpreter GIF]

GIF is from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btjcIAyMNmc).