# Library exists, but can't import

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have installed Python to my Windows11 machine. Trying to run simple MQTT client in my VS Code IDE. Have installed Paho library :

```
pip install paho-mqtt:

Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt in c:\users\g\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py3.11.egg (1.6.1)
```

Got errors on lines

```
import pytest

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pytest'
  File "C:\Python_test\Paho\paho.mqtt.python\tests\test_client.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

and

```
import paho.mqtt.client as client

    Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
    No module named 'paho'
      File "C:\Python_test\Paho\paho.mqtt.python\tests\test_client.py", line 9, in <module>
        import paho.mqtt.client as client
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'
```

Client code:

```
import inspect
import os
import sys
import time
import unicodedata

import pytest

import paho.mqtt.client as client

# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder
cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.split(
                inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0],
            '..', 'test')))
if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)
import paho_test

# Import test fixture
from testsupport.broker import fake_broker


@pytest.mark.parametrize("proto_ver", [
    (client.MQTTv31),
    (client.MQTTv311),
])
class Test_connect(object):
    """
    Tests on connect/disconnect behaviour of the client
    """

    def test_01_con_discon_success(self, proto_ver, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client(
            "01-con-discon-success", protocol=proto_ver)

        def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
            assert rc == 0
            mqttc.disconnect()

        mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect(
                "01-con-discon-success", keepalive=60,
                proto_ver=proto_ver)
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1000)
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            disconnect_packet = paho_test.gen_disconnect()
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1000)
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == disconnect_packet

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()

        packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
        assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

    def test_01_con_failure_rc(self, proto_ver, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client(
            "01-con-failure-rc", protocol=proto_ver)

        def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
            assert rc == 1

        mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect(
                "01-con-failure-rc", keepalive=60,
                proto_ver=proto_ver)
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1000)
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=1)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
            assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()


class TestPublishBroker2Client(object):

    def test_invalid_utf8_topic(self, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client("client-id")

        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            with pytest.raises(UnicodeDecodeError):
                msg.topic
            client.disconnect()

        mqttc.on_message = on_message

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect("client-id")
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(connect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(b"\xff", qos=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(publish_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(publish_packet)

            disconnect_packet = paho_test.gen_disconnect()
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(disconnect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == disconnect_packet

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()

        packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
        assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

    def test_valid_utf8_topic_recv(self, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client("client-id")

        # It should be non-ascii multi-bytes character
        topic = unicodedata.lookup('SNOWMAN')

        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            assert msg.topic == topic
            client.disconnect()

        mqttc.on_message = on_message

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect("client-id")
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(connect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(
                topic.encode('utf-8'), qos=0
            )
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(publish_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(publish_packet)

            disconnect_packet = paho_test.gen_disconnect()
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(disconnect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == disconnect_packet

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()

        packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
        assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

    def test_valid_utf8_topic_publish(self, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client("client-id")

        # It should be non-ascii multi-bytes character
        topic = unicodedata.lookup('SNOWMAN')

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect("client-id")
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(connect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            mqttc.publish(topic, None, 0)
            # Small sleep needed to avoid connection reset.
            time.sleep(0.3)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(
                topic.encode('utf-8'), qos=0
            )
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(publish_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == publish_packet

            mqttc.disconnect()

            disconnect_packet = paho_test.gen_disconnect()
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(disconnect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == disconnect_packet

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()

        packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
        assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

    def test_message_callback(self, fake_broker):
        mqttc = client.Client("client-id")
        userdata = {
            'on_message': 0,
            'callback1': 0,
            'callback2': 0,
        }
        mqttc.user_data_set(userdata)

        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            assert msg.topic == 'topic/value'
            userdata['on_message'] += 1

        def callback1(client, userdata, msg):
            assert msg.topic == 'topic/callback/1'
            userdata['callback1'] += 1

        def callback2(client, userdata, msg):
            assert msg.topic in ('topic/callback/3', 'topic/callback/1')
            userdata['callback2'] += 1

        mqttc.on_message = on_message
        mqttc.message_callback_add('topic/callback/1', callback1)
        mqttc.message_callback_add('topic/callback/+', callback2)

        mqttc.connect_async("localhost", 1888)
        mqttc.loop_start()

        try:
            fake_broker.start()

            connect_packet = paho_test.gen_connect("client-id")
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(connect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == connect_packet

            connack_packet = paho_test.gen_connack(rc=0)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(connack_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(connack_packet)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(b"topic/value", qos=1, mid=1)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(publish_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(publish_packet)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(b"topic/callback/1", qos=1, mid=2)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(publish_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(publish_packet)

            publish_packet = paho_test.gen_publish(b"topic/callback/3", qos=1, mid=3)
            count = fake_broker.send_packet(publish_packet)
            assert count  # Check connection was not closed
            assert count == len(publish_packet)


            puback_packet = paho_test.gen_puback(mid=1)
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(puback_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == puback_packet

            puback_packet = paho_test.gen_puback(mid=2)
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(puback_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == puback_packet

            puback_packet = paho_test.gen_puback(mid=3)
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(puback_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == puback_packet

            mqttc.disconnect()

            disconnect_packet = paho_test.gen_disconnect()
            packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(len(disconnect_packet))
            assert packet_in  # Check connection was not closed
            assert packet_in == disconnect_packet

        finally:
            mqttc.loop_stop()

        packet_in = fake_broker.receive_packet(1)
        assert not packet_in  # Check connection is closed

        assert userdata['on_message'] == 1
        assert userdata['callback1'] == 1
        assert userdata['callback2'] == 2
```

Comment: Do you happen to have several python interpreters or envs? If so, maybe you install in a different env and run in another. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Also have a look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76339821/why-does-visual-studio-code-recognize-numpy-but-not-matplotlib-pyplot-in-python/76339917#76339917